# Unity. Использование кнопки "Назад" для вызова метода

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Можно ли обойтись без методов типа Update что бы заставить кнопку "назад" вызывать какой либо метод? Хотелось бы обойтись без постоянного вызова метода ради одной кнопки.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            do something;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Конечно можно. Вот пример кода https://gist.github.com/Ciantic/471698 но всё таки лучше использовать update

Comment: Нет, нельзя. По крайней мере до выхода новой Input System любая система ввода будет использовать `Update`. В любом случае эту информацию кто-то должен ловить каждый фрейм, что возможно только через `Update`.